# HTML5 Canvas Javascript how to make smooth brush

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, brush

Hello i need make smooth brush likes this:
[image]

I try to create it, i make circle and fill it, but result not successful:
[image]

Can be seen circles.. this is not smooth like first example
my example code:

```js
function distanceBetween(point1, point2) {
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(point2.x - point1.x, 2) + Math.pow(point2.y - point1.y, 2));
}
function angleBetween(point1, point2) {
  return Math.atan2( point2.x - point1.x, point2.y - point1.y );
}

var el = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');

//ctx.fillStyle = "rgba('255, 0, 0, 0.1')";
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.globalAlpha = "0.05";
ctx.lineWidth = 0;
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; 

var isDrawing, lastPoint;

el.onmousedown = function(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  lastPoint = { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY };
};

el.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return;
  
  var currentPoint = { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY };
  var dist = distanceBetween(lastPoint, currentPoint);
  var angle = angleBetween(lastPoint, currentPoint);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < dist; i+=5) {
    x = lastPoint.x + (Math.sin(angle) * i) - 25;
    y = lastPoint.y + (Math.cos(angle) * i) - 25;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x+10, y+10, 20, false, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  
  lastPoint = currentPoint;
};

el.onmouseup = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
};

function clearit() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0, 1000, 1000);
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid #ccc }
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
<input type="button" id="clear-btn" value="Clear it" onclick="clearit()">
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPjwry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with a smaller `globalAlpha` and decrease the stepping (*so you draw more circles*)

```js
function distanceBetween(point1, point2) {
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(point2.x - point1.x, 2) + Math.pow(point2.y - point1.y, 2));
}
function angleBetween(point1, point2) {
  return Math.atan2( point2.x - point1.x, point2.y - point1.y );
}

var el = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');

//ctx.fillStyle = "rgba('255, 0, 0, 0.1')";
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.globalAlpha = "0.01";
ctx.lineWidth = 0;
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; 

var isDrawing, lastPoint;

el.onmousedown = function(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  lastPoint = { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY };
};

el.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return;
  
  var currentPoint = { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY };
  var dist = distanceBetween(lastPoint, currentPoint);
  var angle = angleBetween(lastPoint, currentPoint);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < dist; i+=3) {
    x = lastPoint.x + (Math.sin(angle) * i) - 25;
    y = lastPoint.y + (Math.cos(angle) * i) - 25;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x+10, y+10, 20, false, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  
  lastPoint = currentPoint;
};

el.onmouseup = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
};

function clearit() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0, 1000, 1000);
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid #ccc }
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
<input type="button" id="clear-btn" value="Clear it" onclick="clearit()">
```

Updated codepen: http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/ramqBz

Answer (score 0):

There is more simple solution: just set width of line to 25px

```js
let ctx = this.d.transparentUpdateImage.getContext('2d');

if (!this.lastPos) {
    this.lastPos = {x: x, y: y};
    return
}

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(this.lastPos.x, this.lastPos.y);
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.lineWidth = 25;
ctx.lineTo(x, y);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

this.lastPos = {x: x, y: y};
```